# biblatex: label construction with apostrophe

Tags: biblatex

How can I customize biblatex labels to show the unaltered author's last name? In the following LaTeX example I define a custom alphabetic label style:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
  citestyle = alphabetic, 
  bibstyle = alphabetic, 
  labelalpha = true,
  backend = biber,
  hyperref = true, 
  maxalphanames = 1,
  firstinits = true,
  abbreviate = true,
  backref = false,
  doi = false,
  url = false,
  isbn = false,
  bibwarn = true,
  bibencoding = utf8,
  dateabbrev = true,
  maxbibnames = 10,
  minbibnames = 3
]{biblatex}%

\bibliography{./Literatur.bib}

% Abbrev. for et. al.
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{+}

%% Biblatex Label
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field[compound=false]{labelname}
    \field{label}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{\addnbthinspace}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
    %\field{year}
  }
}

% bibliography
\begin{filecontents}{./Literatur.bib}
@article{otoole_optical_2010,
  title =    {Optical computing for fast light transport analysis},
  pages =    {1-12},
  journaltitle = {ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG)},
  series =   {SIGGRAPH ASIA '10},
  library =  {Seoul, South Korea},
  author =   {{O'Toole}, Matthew and Kutulakos, Kiriakos N},
  date =     2010,
  note =     {ACM ID: 1866165}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

In the literature  \cite{otoole_optical_2010} a very interesting 
approach ...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This nearly gives me the desired result:

[image]

However, I want the exact author's name in the label, which is "O'Toole" (with apostrophe) and not "OToole" (without apostrophe) as in the example. The same issue can be observed for double names with dashes like "Miller-Brown" which are shown as "MillerBrown".

How can I construct the desired biblatex label?

Comment: Your MWE doesn't give me the result you posted. Are you sure the code corresponds to that output?

Comment: I double checked the MWE (local MikTeX and online writeLaTeX), it gives me the posted result. What's your result?

Comment: I do get the same output with a recent `biblatex` 2.9/Biber 1.9 set-up. I think that this is an issue you might want the developers to notify about in the bug tracker (either https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues or https://github.com/plk/biber/issues).

Comment: @Robinaut Have you ever filed a report? Where there any changes, any news to report here?

Comment: Very distantly related: [Ignore Spaces in Author Name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224243/35864).

Comment: See [Alphabetic Labels: Better Control over Non-Alphanumeric Characters #333](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/333) over at the `biblatex` tracker

Answer (score 2):

This has been addressed in the recent update to `biblatex` and Biber (version 3.1 and 2.2 respectively).

With `\DeclareNolabel`  we can now choose exactly those characters to be dropped from label creation, the default is `\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}`. In order to preserve apostrophes you can use

```
\DeclareNolabel{
  \nolabel{\regexp{[\p{S}\p{Z}\p{C}]+}}
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[%
  style = alphabetic, 
  backend = biber,
  maxalphanames = 1,
  firstinits = true,
  abbreviate = true,
  maxbibnames = 10,
  minbibnames = 3
]{biblatex}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{otoole_optical_2010,
  title =    {Optical computing for fast light transport analysis},
  pages =    {1-12},
  journaltitle = {ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG)},
  series =   {SIGGRAPH ASIA '10},
  library =  {Seoul, South Korea},
  author =   {{O'Toole}, Matthew and Kutulakos, Kiriakos N},
  date =     2010,
  note =     {ACM ID: 1866165}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{+}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field[compound=false]{labelname}
    \field{label}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{\addnbthinspace}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\DeclareNolabel{
  \nolabel{\regexp{[\p{S}\p{Z}\p{C}]+}}
}


\begin{document}
In the literature  \cite{otoole_optical_2010} a very interesting 
approach.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]