# Ignore Spaces in Author Name

Tags: biblatex

I am using the alphabetic biblatex style together with the option `maxalphanames=1`. How can I make biblatex ignore any spaces in the author name during label generation?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@Article{DeLorca2015,
  Title   = {Article title},
  Author  = {De Lorca, Antonio and Jekyll, Martin},
  Journal = {Journal title},
  Year    = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
  \cite{DeLorca2015}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE produces the label `[De 15]`, but I'd rather like the label to be `[DeL15]`.

Comment: I guess there is nothing to do with TeX. It is `Biber.pm`, a perl script, doing most of jobs. It should contains something like *take 3 character from this string and save to that string*. And you need to modify it.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are two lines `( $label, $sortlabel ) = @{ $self->_genlabel($citekey) };` `$be->set_field('labelalpha', $label);` generating the label. But I cannot find the definition of `_genlabel`.

Comment: @Symbol 1: Well, this might be a way, but I don't particularly like it as it drastically reduces the documents portability.

Comment: See [Alphabetic Labels: Better Control over Non-Alphanumeric Characters #333](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/333) over at the `biblatex` tracker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with `biblatex` 3.1/Biber 2.2 there is `\DeclareNolabel` which we can use to ignore certain characters when creating the label.

The default is to ignore `[\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]+`. If we want to ignore space characters as well, we only need to add `\p{Z}` (you can read more about these Unicode properties on [perldoc.perl.org *Unicode Character Properties*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties) and for general RegEx in Perl [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html))

```
\DeclareNolabel{
  \nolabel{\regexp{[\p{Z}\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]+}}
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{DeLorca2015,
  Title   = {Article title},
  Author  = {De Lorca, Antonio and Jekyll, Martin},
  Journal = {Journal title},
  Year    = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareNolabel{
  \nolabel{\regexp{[\p{Z}\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]+}}
}

\begin{document}
  \cite{DeLorca2015}
\end{document}
```

[image: output is [DeL15]]

Comment: @Bloops Well, all credits go to PLK for implementing this feature.

Comment: does the `\DeclareNolabel` option work when the `bibstyle` is not `alphabetic`? I am using a custom `.bbx` file with `citestyle=alphabetic`, and having the same problem, but I can't get this solution to work.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett It should. It still works for me if I change `style=alphabetic,` in the MWE to `citestyle=alphabetic,`. If it doesn't work for you maybe something else in your setup is the problem. But that can probably only be investigated with an MWE.